# How to iterate over a list of csv files and compile files with common filenames into a single csv as multiple columns

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, csv, merge, concatenation

I am currently iterating through a list of csv files and want to combine csv files with common filename strings into a single csv file merging the data from the new csv file as a set of two new columns. I am having trouble with the final part of this in that the append command adds the data as rows at the base of the csv. I have tried with *pd.concat*, but must be going wrong somewhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Note the code is using Python 2 - just for compatibility with the software I am using - Python 3 solution welcome if it translates.

Here is the code I'm currently working with:

```
rb_headers = ["OID_RB", "Id_RB", "ORIG_FID_RB", "POINT_X_RB", "POINT_Y_RB"]
for i in coords:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(i, '*RB_bank_xycoords.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(i, header=0, names=rb_headers)
        df2 = df[::-1]

        #Export the inverted RB csv file as a new csv to the original folder overwriting the original
        df2.to_csv(bankcoords+i, index=False)

    
#Iterate through csvs to combine those with similar key strings in their filenames and merge them into a single csv
files_of_interest = {}
forconc = []

for filename in coords:
    if filename[-4:] == '.csv':
        key = filename[:39]
        files_of_interest.setdefault(key, [])
        files_of_interest[key].append(filename)

for key in files_of_interest:
    buff_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for filename in files_of_interest[key]:
        buff_df = buff_df.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

    files_of_interest[key]=buff_df

    redundant_headers = ["OID", "Id", "ORIG_FID", "OID_RB", "Id_RB", "ORIG_FID_RB"]

    outdf = buff_df.drop(redundant_headers, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only to merge in one file:

```
paths_list=['path1', 'path2',...] 
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=";") for f in paths_list]
dfs=pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
dfs.to_csv(...)
```